# Emoji rendering too big in windows 10 browsers

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, emoji

I am working on an HTML email and the problem is that emoji in the email is rendering too big in browsers in windows 10, here is a comparison.

Render in windows 10:

[image]

Render everywhere else:

[image]

I have tested in all major browsers in windows 10 and I can see this problem persisting across browsers. Is there a way to fix it using CSS? Below is the HTML code rendering the line having emoji.

```html
<p style="
                          margin: 0;
                          font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode',
                            'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
                          font-weight: 700;
                          font-size: 12px;
                          line-height: 14px;
                          letter-spacing: 1px;
                          text-align: center;
                          color: #4c7b99;
                        ">
   ORDER NO.
</p>
```

Please suggest a solution which should work in HTML emails, as they only support a subset of CSS. Thanks

Comment: Where does it render as expected, is it a different Windows version or on a Mac/iOS?

Comment: I does not render too big on my Windows10 Edge, Chrome or Firefox browsers. Could you specify exactly which browsers and version numbers is doesn't work on for you?Are you sure it isn't just your Windows10 implementation? Can you try it on other Windows10 machines? Also does running your actual snippet show the problem for you?